# How to splice a string in java

Tags: java, string

So if I have a string such that

```
String name = "Daniel";
int age = 18;
```

If I want to create a string username using for example the first 3 letters of the name + the age, how can I manipulate the name to get the first 3 letters?

I understand that you can do the string.split() but I don't understand how this is applicable to this scenario.

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question but as you can probably tell I'm still a noob. Thanks in advance

Comment: use the substring method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should take a look at the substring method. here's an example:

```java
String myString = "this is a test string";
String subString = myString(0 /* begin index included letter*/, 4 /* end index excluded letter */) => // subString is now "this"
```

in your case it would look like that:

```java
public static String extractInfos(String name, int age) {
    if (name.length() >= 3) {
        return name.substring(0, 3) + String.valueOf(age);
    }
    return name + String.valueOf(age);
}

// test section
String name = "Daniel";
int age = 18;
extractInfos(name, age); // outs "Dan18"
```

Comment: The better answer, since it accounts for names with less than 3 letters.

Answer (score 5):

```
String username = name.substring(0, 3) + String.valueOf(age);
```